# Stripping chars from string in F#

Tags: .net, string, f#, fold

I am new to functional programming and F# and there sure is a lot of information on how to do this (removing specific characters from a string) in F# but I came across the following function and would appreciate a little help to understand exactly what's going on:

```
let stripchars chars str =
  Seq.fold
    (fun (str: string) chr ->
      str.Replace(chr |> Char.ToUpper |> string, "").Replace(chr |> Char.ToLower |> string, ""))
    str chars
```

I used the stripchars function by calling it in a split function I defined like this:

```
let split (str : string) =
    ((stripchars "?,.,!,," str).Split ' ') |> Array.toList
```

What I have a hard time understanding right now is, in the function stripchars, when the argument "chars" is passed, containing the sequence of characters to remove from the string str, it's not even used in the code until the last line "str chars". So how can this work?

Comment: `chars` is not the last line of the function. It is just one function that is really long so they separated it up across a few lines. It is really `Seq.fold <some fun> str chars`. Because the `<some fun>` is so long it is done that way for readability. Put it all on one line and run it to see.

Comment: I get it now, thank's alot!

Comment: If you're using this on large strings, calling String.Replace twice for each character you want to strip is going to be pretty dang slow. If you've got a very large input, and a small list of characters to strip, this function traverses the small list of characters once, and the large input many many times, which is exactly backwards. For small input strings, it doesn't really matter, of course, unless this function is called a lot.

Comment: Why do you have so many commas in `"?,.,!,,"`? It doesn't need to be comma-delimited in that code, it's just using `chars` as a sequence of characters, which all .NET strings inherently are. Right now you're stripping all commas from the string four times.

Comment: @JoelMueller , thanks for your feedback! Since I only need to remove periods, commas, question marks and exclamation marks, there is really no need to check both uppercase and lowercase letters and call Replace twice. I changed the code only call it once: `to.str.Replace(chr |> string, "")` and when I call the stripchars function I removed the extra commas: `((stripchars "?.!," str).Split ' ') |> Array.toList`. I guess it is still a fairly expensive operation on large strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Guy Coder points out in the above comment, the function body has unorthodox formatting. It'd probably be more readable if you extract the accumulator function to an inner, nested function:

```
let stripchars chars str =
    let removeOneChar (str : string) chr =
        str.Replace(chr |> Char.ToUpper |> string, "").Replace(chr |> Char.ToLower |> string, "")
    Seq.fold removeOneChar str chars
```

The return value of this function is the last expression, `Seq.fold removeOneChar str chars`.

The `removeOneChar` function has the type `string -> char -> string`.

Comment: Thank's for the explanation! Your reformatted function works like a charm and is indeed more readable.